# I can't install Vagrant 1.8.1 for VirtualBox 5.0 version

Tags: vagrant, virtualbox, homestead, laravel-5

I'm new to GNU/Linux. I'm using Debian 8.

I installed "VirtualBox" and "Vagrant" (I installed Vagrant from the terminal) and all fine but I upgraded "VirtualBox" to version 5.0 and run "Vagrant" I said it was not compatible with the version of "VirtualBox" and pedia to change to previous versions.

I uninstalled "Vagrant" and I download the new version from the official website (www.vagrantup.com/downloads.html) [in my case vagrant_1.8.1_x86_64.deb] but threw me run installation failure.

Then try installing from the terminal, typing `sudo apt-get install vagrant 1.8.1` and says "vagrant is already in its latest version." and obtain the version with `vagrant -v` says "bash: vagrant: the order was not found"

What should I do to install "Vagrant 1.8.1" or fix the problem?

[Vagrant Installer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nTueo.jpg)

[Vagrant Terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tr30H.jpg)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Further research and found some commands that helped me in my problem.**

https://teamtreehouse.com/community/vagrant-up-command-not-found
http://hipertextual.com/archivo/2014/02/instalar-paquetes-deb-con-dpkg/

1) Clear everything that contained the word "vagrant" in my laptop.

2) Run the terminal the following command "sudo find / -name vagrant" and showed me "/usr/share/doc/ vagrant" so I deleted also whit "sudo rm -R /usr/share/doc/vagrant"

3) I go to the folder where the installer was downloaded from "vagrant 1.8.1" with $ cd Downloads

4) Run "dpkg -i vagrant_1.8.1_x86_64.deb"

5) Again try vagrant -v

And ready vagrant 1.8.1 installed on my laptop.! :D

**Very Thanks and I hope I can help someone who present the same problem.**